# I have problem in implementing generic repository

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, repository

I want to build generic repository to make it easy in implementing..now I want to make interface to used it in dependency injection in my domain service but I can't

I want to build generic repository to make it easy in implementing.I created generic abstract repository that get entity and its context.now I want to make interface to used it in dependency injection in my domain service

my generic repository:

```
 public abstract class Repository<T,K>:IRepository<T,K>
    {
        private Type t;
        private K _Context;
        private bool disposed = false;
        public Repository(K Context)
        {
            _Context = Context;
        }
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _Context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        public void Delete(object id)
        {
            T t = _Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
            _Context.Set<T>().Remove(t);
        }

        public T Get(object id)
        {
            return _Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> getList()
        {
            return _Context.Set<T>().ToList();
        }

        public void insert(T t)
        {
            _Context.Set<T>().Add(t);
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            _Context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public  void Update(T t)
        {
            _Context.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

my repository interface:

```
    public interface IRepository<T,K> where T : BaseEntity where K : BaseContext<K>
    {
        T Get(object id);
        IEnumerable<T> getList();
        void insert(T t);
        void Delete(object id);
        void Update(T t);
        void Save();

    }
```

my error is `"the Type 'T' can not be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type....The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'IRepository'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'DomainModel.BaseEntity"` and I want to know how can I resolve this problem

Comment: I think the rest of the error is important as it usually contains some explanation. Why not post it?

Comment: this is error explanation for this problem "The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'IRepository<T, K>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'DomainModel.BaseEntity'"

Comment: Thanks, but please put the error in the question, and delete the comment and your answer, since it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the *where* constraints on the *class Repository<T,K>* as well i.e.:

```
public abstract class Repository<T,K>:IRepository<T,K> where T : BaseEntity where K : BaseContext<K>
```

This is because C# knows nothing about the T in *Repository<T,K>*, but it needs to satisfy the *where* criteria in *IRepository<T,K>*